# NHibernate object id is returning incorrect value

Tags: c#, combobox, c#-2.0

I am using NHibernate and this is not a Homework.

Suppose I have retrieved an object of type `Faculty`(suppose Faculty of Engineering in the University of XYZ) from the database. It has 5 child objects associated with it of type `Department` and should contain IDs 2,4,5,8 and 9 according to the database-table.

My 1st problem is, **I see that the associated objects always have `ID` set as `0`.**

Faculty-ID is loading correctly.

My 2nd problem is, I need to load them into a combo box and want the object selected whose ID is 5.

How can I solve the problem of ID set to 0? I don't know why it is happening.

How to select the object of ID==5?

### Faculty.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping
    xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="UserManagememntApplication.BO"
    assembly="UserManagememntApplication.BO" >

  <class name="Faculty" table="b_Faculty">
    <id column="ID" name="ID" type="System.Int32" >
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property column="Code" name="Code" />
    <property column="Name" name="Name" />
    <property column="IsActive" name="IsActive" />

    <bag name="DepartmentItems" table="b_Department">
      <key column="FacultyID"/>
      <one-to-many class="Department" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### Department.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-mapping
    xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
    namespace="UserManagememntApplication.BO"
    assembly="UserManagememntApplication.BO" >

  <class name="Department" table="b_Department">
    <id column="ID" name="ID" type="System.Int32" >
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>

    <property column="Code" name="Code" />
    <property column="Name" name="Name" />
    <property column="IsActive" name="IsActive" />

    <many-to-one name="Faculty" class="Faculty" column="FacultyID" unique="true"  />

    <bag name="TeacherItems" table="b_Teacher">
      <key column="DepartmentID"/>
      <one-to-many class="Teacher" />
    </bag>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### b_Faculty

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[b_Faculty](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_b_Faculty] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

### b_Department

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[b_Department](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FacultyID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Code] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_b_Department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

## Edit:

### Faculty.cs

```
public class Faculty : BusinessObject<Faculty>
    {
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Department> DepartmentItems { get; set; }
    }
```

### Department.cs

```
public class Department : BusinessObject<Department>
    {
        public virtual string Code { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }

        public virtual Faculty Faculty { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<Teacher> TeacherItems { get; set; }
    }
```

### BusinessObject.cs

```
public abstract class BusinessObject<T> : IBusinessObject where T : BusinessObject<T>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public static bool operator ==(BusinessObject<T> item1, BusinessObject<T> item2)
        {
            bool same = false;

            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && !object.ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
            {
                if (item1.ID == item2.ID)
                {
                    same = true;
                }
            }

            else
            {
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(item1, null) && object.ReferenceEquals(item2, null))
                {
                    same = true;
                }
            }

            return same;
        }

        public static bool operator !=(BusinessObject<T> item1, BusinessObject<T> item2)
        {
            return !(item1 == item2);
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            //If "obj" is null, they are obviously not equal.
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            //If the objects are the same instance, they must be equal.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, obj))
            {
                return true;
            }

            //If the objects are not the same type, they cannot be equal.
            if (this.GetType() != obj.GetType())
            {
                return false;
            }

            T objCustomer = (T)obj;

            if (this.ID > 0 && objCustomer.ID > 0)
            {
                if (this.ID.Equals(objCustomer.ID))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }
            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (this.ID <= 0)
            {
                return base.GetHashCode();
            }
            else
            {
                return ID.GetHashCode();
            }
        }
    }
```

### FacultyRepository.cs

```
public class FacultyRepository : Repository<Faculty>
    {
    }
```

### DepartmentRepository.cs

```
public class DepartmentRepository : Repository<Department>
    {
    }
```

### Repository.cs

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
    {
        ISession _session;

        public Repository() 
        {
            _session = SessionFactory.GetOpenSession();
        }

        public T Get(object id)
        {
            T obj = default(T);

            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();
                    obj = (T)_session.Get<T>(id);
                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }

            return obj;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get(string fieldName, object fieldValue)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> list = null;

            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();
                    list = (IEnumerable<T>)_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T))
                        .Add(new NHibernate.Expression.EqExpression(fieldName, fieldValue))
                        .List<T>();

                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }

            return list;
        }

        public IEnumerable<T> Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<T> list = null;

            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();
                    list = (IEnumerable<T>)_session.CreateCriteria(typeof(T)).List<T>();
                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }

            return list;
        }

        public void SaveOrUpdate(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();
                    _session.SaveOrUpdateCopy(obj);
                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void SaveOrUpdate(IEnumerable<T> objs)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();

                    foreach (T obj in objs)
                    {
                        _session.SaveOrUpdate(obj);
                    }

                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void Delete(T obj)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();
                    _session.Delete(obj);
                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();                
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void Delete(IEnumerable<T> objs)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();

                    foreach (T obj in objs)
                    {
                        _session.Delete(obj);
                    }

                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();
                _session.Clear();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void DeleteAll()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!_session.Transaction.IsActive)
                {
                    _session.BeginTransaction();

                    DetachedCriteria criterion = DetachedCriteria.For<T>();
                    IList<T> list = criterion.GetExecutableCriteria(_session).List<T>();

                    foreach (T item in list)
                    {
                        _session.Delete(item);
                    }

                    _session.Transaction.Commit();
                    _session.Flush();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(CustomErrorMessage.TransactionAlreadyInProgress);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _session.Transaction.Rollback();

                throw ex;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (_session != null)
            {
                _session.Clear();
                _session.Close();
                _session = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

### SessionFactory.cs

```
public class SessionFactory
    {
        private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = null;
        private SessionFactory(){}

        static SessionFactory()
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
                configuration.Configure();
                _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
            }
        }

        public static ISession GetOpenSession()
        {
            return _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
        }
    }
```

## **This is all I have.**

Comment: You should probably make a separate question for the combobox population.

Comment: Can you please provide some sort of schema dump for that table, and your NHibernate mapping?  It would make this problem significantly easier to debug.

Comment: Is the ID of Faculty loaded correctly?

Comment: Yes, Faculty-ID is loaded correctly.

Comment: Could you provide the code of your class the entity is mapped to? At least the definition of Id and any code that works with this Id would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extremely wild guess. Could you try to run your code without the equality comparers and the `Equals` implementation and see whether that helps, so with the following implementation:

```
public abstract class BusinessObject<T> : IBusinessObject where T : BusinessObject<T>
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Another thing you may want to try is to set the `ID` to private:

```
public abstract class BusinessObject<T> : IBusinessObject where T : BusinessObject<T>
{
    public int ID { get; private set; }
}
```

See what the effect of that is.

Comment: I have solved my problem. In 'BusinessObject.cs', I forgot to add the modifier virtual to the property ID. As soon as I added the keyword virtual, it is working fine. Since NHibernate was not giving any warning, I was overlooking it all the way.

Comment: That's very strange because NHibernate throws when you load an object with a non-virtual property. Glad you found it though. If I change my answer, do I get the bounty? Just kidding :P.

Comment: Now, to get 50 bounty-points, can you please solve my ComboBox-related problem?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the `ComboBox` issue, I would do the following:

```
var faculty = GetFaculty();
int selectedID = 5;

int selectedIndex = -1;

comboBox1.BeginUpdate();

comboBox1.Items.Clear();

foreach (var department in faculty.DepartmentItems)
{
    int index = comboBox1.Items.Add(department);

    if (department.ID == selectedID)
        selectedIndex = index;
}

if (selectedIndex != -1)
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = selectedIndex;

comboBox1.EndUpdate();
```

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but the above approach is the one I would take. If this is not what you're looking for, could you please expand the question?

Comment: This is not working! I am trying it myself. But points to you anyway.

Comment: Yes, this happens sometimes. I've updated the answer to work with the `SelectedIndex` instead. Btw, I don't think you've awarded the bounty yet. I believe you have to do that manually.

Comment: See this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027137/how-to-solve-this-combobox-item-setting-problem

Comment: I think this has to do with your equality implementation. Gave a try at your other question :).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the id returned as 0 after doing a select.
I'm using Fluent Nhibernate and had the id field both declared in the persistent class and the child class. 
Only had to remove the id from the child class.